# android : LayoutInflater in static method

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

i want to call LayoutInflater from static method as below :

```
    private static void inflateLayout_keluarga_pp(int counter2, String name) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutkeluarga, null);
..................
..................
}
```

this is how i call method `inflateLayout_keluarga_pp` :

```
    public static void onRetrieve(int position){
    List<ModelKeluargaPP> mk = helper.getSelectTable_Marital();
        for (int i=0; i<mk.size();i++){
        inflateLayout_keluarga_pp(i,mk.get(position).getAnggota_pp());


  }
}
```

but i got error in `getActivity()`, they said : `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment` i need to make this method into static. how to fix it? i hope someone can help to solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: You have to learn java basics, static means - can not use this object or any field or any non static method

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` belongs to the instance of the current `Fragment`; it cannot be part of a static context.

When you declare a method `static`, you are stating that this method will not belong to each particular instance of the `Class`; it belongs to the `Class` itself. Since the static method will be available regardless if you instantiate an object of the `Class`, you cannot guarantee that object members and methods (that are not static) will be available. Hence you cannot reference "things" that will be available only when the object is instantiated inside a static method that will always be available.

Like Jems said, if you need to access the `Fragment` you need to always make it available within the method's scope. This can be accomplished by either passing a `Fragment` to the static method or by instantiating it inside the static method.

Answer (score 1):

If it must be static, pass a reference to the `Fragment` you want to call getActivity on into the method.

```
private static void inflateLayout_keluarga_pp(int counter2, String name, Fragment myFragment) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)myFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: but i call that method like this : 
      inflateLayout_keluarga_pp(counter,"family");

Comment: I cannot see where you are calling it or where this code is placed, so I can't tell what Fragment you would need to pass it. If you don't have one, you can probably pass an Activity or some other Context if you changed the parameter type I added appropriately.